# Create a Group in a Modern site and manage file's permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, modern-experience

I have some folders and documents and I need to give them different permissions to the people who aren't owners of the site.
I need to create some groups of people, so that they can only be seen for those who are part of a certain group.

But I can't find how to manage groups in the modern sites. When I click  the "Members button" (picture below), it only has the option to add members and change their group. I want to know where I can change the permissions of groups, create and delete groups, etc..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to site settings-> Site Permissions, then click Advanced permission settings.
You could change the permissions of groups, create and delete groups in that page.

[image]

[image]